# select option from centralised list

Tags: php, html

I have a select option list which is repeated many times over a number of pages. Is there a method of referring out to have one list that all the references use?

```
<select name="staff_member[]">
<option value="'.$row->staff_member.'">'.$row->staff_member.'</option>
<option value="adam">adam</option>
<option value="ben">ben</option>
<option value="clive">clive</option>
<option value="etc etc etc"..
</select>
```

I have a long list of staff members and it rotates regularly, so I'd like to have this list in one place and just refer to it in the html / php. For menus, I've been using 'php include' but I haven't found a way of doing the same with that here as the code sits within a while loop which has multiple switch / case statements to format the page. just inserting an 'include' statement doesn't work (although it may just be the way I've formatted it).

I'd be grateful of any pointers please?

Comment: Write a function for this, (including the query), and call it when you need.

Comment: @lolka_bolka That's a good thought. I hadn't considered a function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a table with the staff members is, and referring to this table in the select / option as follows:-

```
<select name="staff_member[]">
<option value="'.$row2->staff_member.'">'.$row2->staff_member.'</option>';
$repairer= mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT staff_member FROM staff");
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($staff_member)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row[staff_member].'">'.$row[staff_member].'</option>' ;
} 
echo '</select></td>
```

I had to break in and out of php / html (hence the echo statements) as this part of the code exists within a while loop and I didn't know how else to do it, however it works now and as the staff rotate, I only have to update the one table. Much easier.

I did consider the Function option suggested, however I needed the fastest option and will have to save learning more about functions for another time. I expect that there will be loads of benefit once I get my head around them though :)